# CheckBox (from hyperref) - tick by default

Tags: hyperref, forms

This may seem basic, but is there a way to make checkboxes ticked automatically? E.g.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}

\CheckBox[name=ch1]{Yes}

\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

giving [image]

I'd like the above to be checked by default. Then in the `.pdf` one can uncheck it by clicking on the box as required.

I'm reading the [hyperref manual](http://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/manual.html) and under `6.2 Forms optional parameters` it lists  the option with default as `checked boolean false` - I'm not sure how to pass this into `\begin{Form}` with a new default.

If there's an alternative method not involving `hyperref` I'm open to that also.

Am using EMACS & Auctex. If this is possible and there's some simpler way I could have looked it up (e.g. show/modify defaults for `Form` environment) up would be grateful for any pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The check box must have the option `checked`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\CheckBox[checked,name=ch1]{Yes}

\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

For change the default you can use in the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\Fld@checkedtrue
\makeatother
```

Or only for some form:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}
\makeatletter\Fld@checkedtrue\makeatother 
\CheckBox[name=ch1]{Yes}
\CheckBox[name=ch1]{No}
\end{Form}


\begin{Form}
\makeatletter\Fld@checkedfalse\makeatother 
\CheckBox[name=ch1]{Yes}
\CheckBox[name=ch1]{No}
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, perfect! What lead you to this answer ? (I'm still not getting it from the docs). I'm wondering if I can set it as an environment default as I have many boxes... Also, is this a general principle - i.e. if an `environment` has a default like `checked false` then is it reversed by using `checked`?

Comment: @dardisco I just tried to do in this way and see what happen `:)`. Change the default option is less intuitive, but see the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks again, even better. Works fine so the rest is academic. It seems you're temporarily making `Fld@checked` mean `Fldatchecked` before calling `CheckBox` is this correct? How would I have been able to tell that the name of the variable I'm trying to change is `Fldatchecked` - is this related to the `Form` environment or the `.pdf` format?

Comment: @dardisco see [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do) As far I know is not documented how to use `\Fld@checked` but browsing in `.sty` files sometimes you can imagine tricks like this one.

Comment: Yes, I was reading this one before you suggested. Quite the imagination! \* looks at `.sty` files \*